# PHP enchant not working

Tags: php, wamp, enchant

I want to use enchant in my PHP code (I am running WAMP server). I have enabled enchant extension in php.ini and I also added PHP path to system variables. When I start the server it shows the following error

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_enchant.dll - The specified
>   procedure could not be found

but I have php_enchant.dll placed in this directory.

Each time when I run the code I get fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function enchant_broker_init()

So whats wrong with enchant, why it is not working?

Comment: Solved - it was some kind of enchant.dll mistake. I just took enchant.dll from one of the latest php versions and replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed like:

Using the wampmanager (the W icon in the system tray ) do

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> (and click on the version number)
```

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild all the SYMLINKS in the apache/bin folder, and restart Apache. This should fix the issue and stop the errors from appearing in the php error log.

IF NOT:

TO CORRECT THE SECOND ISSUE

Edit the \wamp\script\config.inc.php file and find the code that sets this variable $phpDllToCopy and replace it with this code.

```
$phpDllToCopy = array (
    'icudt52.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.6.a2
    'icuin52.dll',
    'icuio52.dll',
    'icule52.dll',
    'iculx52.dll',
    'icutest52.dll',
    'icutu52.dll',
    'icuuc52.dll',
    'icudt51.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.5.6
    'icuin51.dll',
    'icuio51.dll',
    'icule51.dll',
    'iculx51.dll',
    'icutest51.dll',
    'icutu51.dll',
    'icuuc51.dll',
    'icudt50.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.5
    'icuin50.dll',
    'icuio50.dll',
    'icule50.dll',
    'iculx50.dll',
    'icutest50.dll',
    'icutu50.dll',
    'icuuc50.dll',
    'icudt49.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajouts pour éviter unknown error PHP 5.3/5.4
    'icuin49.dll',
    'icuio49.dll',
    'icule49.dll',
    'iculx49.dll',
    'icutest49.dll',
    'icutu49.dll',
    'icuuc49.dll',
    'libeay32.dll',
    'libsasl.dll', //[modif oto] - Ajout pour éviter unknown error
    'libintl.dll',
    'php5isapi.dll',
    'php5nsapi.dll',
    'ssleay32.dll',
    'php5ts.dll',
    'fribidi.dll', //[modif oto] - Ci-contre et dessous pour PHP 5.2.x
    'fdftk.dll',   // Peuvent être supprimés pour PHP 5.3.0 ou plus
    'libmcrypt.dll',
    'libmhash.dll',
    'libmysql.dll',
    'libmysqli.dll',
    'msql.dll',
    'ntwdblib.dll',
    'php5activescript.dll',
    );
```

Comment: Still nothing, when I start the server I also get this: "The procedure entry piont php_checkuid could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll"
When I go to wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP extensions it shows that php_ enchant is avaliable and everythint is fine

Comment: Still stuck with this